# Using Flexboxgrid or Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I may have a very stupid question for some of you, but I am a beginner, and need a little help from some of you who have experience in this area. 
For example, I work freelance or have my own business where I do web design with HTML, CSS and JS. 
Now I feel very comfortable writing my code with the FLEXBOXGrid system instead of maybe Bootstrap4 or something like that.

does it matter, if I use the Flexboxgrid system or bootstrap or maybe raw Html,css without frameworks?

Is it perhaps better paid to do it with Bootstrap than with Flexboxgrid?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlexboxGrid` http://flexboxgrid.com/ is just a grid.  If you need make things like modals, tooltips, etc. use `Bootstrap`.  Bootstrap offers the grid and other components.

That said, do what you feel comfortable with.  But a few caveats:

1) When using a framework, it's good to know the underlying technology and how it works, because you can debug your code faster and make optimizations easier.

2) You also don't need to know the underlying technology all that well to use a framework.  That's why the framework was invented.  It was made to speed up the entire dev process.  So by all means, use Bootstrap if you need a suite of components, use FlexboxGrid if you just need a grid.  You can also make a custom build of Bootstrap.  A quick Google only turned up a custom build of Bootstrap 3 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/  But if you're using `npm` to get your libraries you can probably import only the parts of the framework you need.

3) If you're looking to just get the job done for the front-end try approaching it like this:
 - What does the client need (modals, grids, static content, etc?)
 - If client needs more than static content and a grid, use Bootstrap
 - Checkout bootstraps Docs, also checkout other forms of bootstrap.  There's two that I love:  https://github.com/thednp/bootstrap.native
and https://reactstrap.github.io/

If you're not looking to add more overhead, go with Bootstrap Native.

You're going to get paid based on the agreed upon price.  But if you make a fantastic looking site quickly, you may get more.  Remember that when using Bootstrap, you can customize the CSS to essentially add your own theme.  There are also plenty of free themes out there.

Best of luck